# How does SQLite's "PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON" reference the foreign keys' tables?

Tags: sqlite, foreign-keys

SQLite is treating foreign key relationships differently from what I had thought:

I have a change in my data model, splitting one table (say
`A`) into two (say `A` and `A1`).
So I renamed `A` to `A_tmp`, created the new `A` and `A1`, then populated `A` and `A1` from the data in `A_tmp`.
When all was done and verified, I dropped table `A_tmp`.

Unfortunately with `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON` rows in other tables referencing `A` were deleted, even if the new `A` had all the IDs (keys) needed.
(I have a `REFERENCES A(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE` in the definition of some other tables.)

How does SQLite's "PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON" reference the foreign keys' tables?

Does SQLite reference tables by name?

That would be the only explanation why the other table rows were removed.

## Sample session

This is a demonstration of the problem (some non-essential output removed for brevity):

```sqlite3
SQLite version 3.44.0 2023-11-01 11:23:50
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;
sqlite> CREATE TABLE A (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, A_1 VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL);
sqlite> CREATE TABLE B (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL REFERENCES A(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE, B_1 VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL);
sqlite> INSERT INTO A (ID, A_1) VALUES (1, 'foo-bar');
sqlite> INSERT INTO B (ID, B_1) VALUES (1, 'anything');
sqlite> .dump
#...
INSERT INTO A VALUES(1,'foo-bar');
INSERT INTO B VALUES(1,'anything');
#...
sqlite> ALTER TABLE A RENAME TO A_tmp;
sqlite> CREATE TABLE A1 (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, A1_1 VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL);
sqlite> CREATE TABLE A (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, A_1 INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES A1(ID) ON DELETE RESTRICT, A_2 VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL);
sqlite> INSERT INTO A1 (ID, A1_1) VALUES (1, 'foo');
sqlite> INSERT INTO A (ID, A_1, A_2) VALUES (1, 1, 'bar');
sqlite> .dump
INSERT INTO A_tmp VALUES(1,'foo-bar');
INSERT INTO B VALUES(1,'anything');
INSERT INTO A1 VALUES(1,'foo');
INSERT INTO A VALUES(1,1,'bar');
# So the data is all there, drop the old table A_tmp
sqlite> DROP TABLE A_tmp;
sqlite> .dump
INSERT INTO A1 VALUES(1,'foo');
INSERT INTO A VALUES(1,1,'bar');
# the row in B vanished while its foreign key A.ID still exists!
```

Comment: Please ask 1 (specific reserched non-duplicate) question.

Comment: It's basically one question: If a `.dump` dis not show any "table ID" other than the table name, why would SQLite reference something different than the name specified. Or maybe: How to work-around that. That *could* be different questions all using the same data base schema, but would that be efficient?

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. PS Please ask 1 question. (Not a bunch of questions,  now.) PS Debug questions require a [mre]. [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 1):

After a table is renamed, all the references point to the new name:

```sql
PRAGMA FOREIGN_KEYS = ON;

CREATE TABLE a (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, str TEXT);
CREATE TABLE b (id INTEGER, aid INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY(aid) REFERENCES a(id) ON DELETE CASCADE);

INSERT INTO a VALUES (1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c'), (4, 'd');

INSERT INTO b VALUES (11, 1), (12, 2), (13, 3), (14, 4);

ALTER TABLE a RENAME TO a_tmp;
.d b
```

Output:

```sql
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE b (id INTEGER, aid INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY(aid) REFERENCES "a_tmp"(id) ON DELETE CASCADE);
INSERT INTO b VALUES(11,1); --                                        ~~~~~
INSERT INTO b VALUES(12,2);
INSERT INTO b VALUES(13,3);
INSERT INTO b VALUES(14,4);
COMMIT;
```

As the `FOREIGN KEY` constraint can't be dropped in Sqlite, you need to rename `b` to `b_tmp`, create a new `b` with a new constraint referencing the new table, and copy the data.

```sql
PRAGMA FOREIGN_KEYS = OFF;
ALTER TABLE a RENAME TO a_tmp;
CREATE TABLE a1 (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, str TEXT);
CREATE TABLE a2 (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, str TEXT);

INSERT INTO a1 SELECT * FROM a_tmp WHERE id % 2 == 0;
INSERT INTO a2 SELECT * FROM a_tmp WHERE id % 2 == 1;
DROP TABLE a_tmp;

PRAGMA FOREIGN_KEYS = ON;

ALTER TABLE b RENAME TO b_tmp;
CREATE TABLE b (id INTEGER, aid INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY(aid) REFERENCES a1(id) ON DELETE CASCADE);
INSERT INTO b SELECT * FROM b_tmp;
DROP TABLE b_tmp;

SELECT * FROM b;
.d b
```

Comment: Doing a `.dump´ before renaming, there is no indication that SQLite uses anything other than table *names*, but it seems SQLite actually uses *table IDs* that don't change when renaming the table.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the only way to to that without moving a lot of data is this (the actual schema references `A.ID` from multiple tables, not just `B`; the demo is just a minimal example):

1. Instead of "renaming the old `A` to `A_tmp`, then adding a new `A`" do "first add the new table `A1` and populate it with values derived from `A.A_1`, then insert a new foreign key column `A_2` to the existing table `A`". This is a bit tricky as the `NOT NULL` foreign key constraint requires a `DEFAUT` value, however. Maybe use just any value of `A1_ID` temporarily.
2. Update `A.A_2` with the correct foreign key `A1.ID` matching `A.A_1` and also modify `A.A_1`.

That way there is no "new" table `A` that would break the foreign key constraint; instead there is a "modified" table `A`.

I tried it with the demo given:

```sqlite3
sqlite> CREATE TABLE A1 (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, A1_1 VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL);
sqlite> INSERT INTO A1 (ID, A1_1) VALUES (1, 'foo');
# The following is needed, because otherwise I got "Runtime error: Cannot add a REFERENCES column with non-NULL default value"
sqlite> PRAGMA FOREIGN_KEYS = OFF;
sqlite> ALTER TABLE A ADD COLUMN A_2 INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 1 REFERENCES A1(ID) ON DELETE RESTRICT;
sqlite> PRAGMA FOREIGN_KEYS = ON;
sqlite> UPDATE A SET A_1='bar', A_2=1 WHERE A_1='foo-bar';
# add some more data:
sqlite> INSERT INTO A (A_2, A_1) VALUES (1, 'baz');
sqlite> INSERT INTO A1 (ID, A1_1) VALUES (2, 'Doe');
sqlite> INSERT INTO A (A_2, A_1) VALUES (2, 'Jane');
sqlite> INSERT INTO A (A_2, A_1) VALUES (2, 'James');
# assuming we know that the new IDs added to A are 2 and 3:
sqlite> INSERT INTO B VALUES(2, 'more');
sqlite> INSERT INTO B VALUES(3, 'stuff');
sqlite> .dump
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE A (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, A_1 VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL, A_2 INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 1 REFERENCES A1(ID) ON DELETE RESTRICT);
INSERT INTO A VALUES(1,'bar',1);
INSERT INTO A VALUES(2,'baz',1);
INSERT INTO A VALUES(3,'Jane',2);
INSERT INTO A VALUES(4,'James',2);
CREATE TABLE B (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL REFERENCES A(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE, B_1 VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO B VALUES(1,'anything');
INSERT INTO B VALUES(2,'more');
INSERT INTO B VALUES(3,'stuff');
CREATE TABLE A1 (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, A1_1 VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO A1 VALUES(1,'foo');
INSERT INTO A1 VALUES(2,'Doe');
DELETE FROM sqlite_sequence;
INSERT INTO sqlite_sequence VALUES('A',4);
INSERT INTO sqlite_sequence VALUES('A1',2);
COMMIT;
```